# Spring MVC Controller show 404

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

All i need help
this is my simple controller when i try to hit the url on postman it's 
**show 404 => response** can any one tell me why it's come. i'm using the spring-boot project.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/rtb")
public class RtbTestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/naveen", "/nabeel", "/harsh"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView rtbResponseValidator(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

        HashMap<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.put("pakistan", "zindabad");
        model.put("indian", "Zindabad");

        return new ModelAndView("openRTB", model);
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the URL for which you are getting 404 ?

Comment: http://localhost:9191/rtb/naveen, http://localhost:9191/rtb/nabeel, http://localhost:9191/rtb/harsh

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
@Controller
    @RequestMapping(value = "/rtb")
    public class RtbTestController {

        @RequestMapping(value = {"/naveen", "/nabeel", "/harsh"}, method = RequestMethod.GET, headers= "Accept=application/json")
        public ModelAndView rtbResponseValidator(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

            HashMap<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            model.put("pakistan", "zindabad");
            model.put("indian", "Zindabad");

            return new ModelAndView("openRTB", model);
        }

    }
```

Comment: thanks for replay but main issue is current project base on web.xml configuration while i'm trying to add web.xml less mapping controller and trying to using the annotation base controller in that case it show error of 404 not found the url path

Comment: can you share your web.xml

Comment: sorry not able to share file but in web.xml the old controller configure             
<servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>adserver</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/nexAgeBidder</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>